# Flutter iOS RevenueCat uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, revenuecat

I got this error in console:

```
[Purchases] - INFO: There is no singleton instance. Make sure you configure Purchases before trying to get the default instance.
*** Assertion failure in +[RCCommonFunctionality getPurchaserInfoWithCompletionBlock:], RCCommonFunctionality.m:118
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'You must call setup first.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1a0379654 0x1a009bbcc 0x1a027c6ec 0x1a06c216c 0x1032908ac 0x1032cdf9c 0x1032cc0d4 0x105c3ae30 0x1053ef758 0x1056d58b4 0x1053f90ec 0x1053fb818 0x1a02f8134 0x1a02f7e50 0x1a02f752c 0x1a02f253c 0x1a02f1ba8 0x1aa461344 0x1a442d3e4 0x102c4069c 0x1a01798f0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00000001a016ed88 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
->  0x1a016ed88 <+8>:  b.lo   0x1a016eda4               ; <+36>
    0x1a016ed8c <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x1a016ed90 <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x1a016ed94 <+20>: bl     0x1a014dad0               ; cerror_nocancel
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
Lost connection to device.
```

However, this is an intermittent problem (i.e: doesn't always happen). In fact, I have setup the `Purchases` instance at startup (i.e: immediately after user is authenticated and I got the UID):

```
 await Purchases.setDebugLogsEnabled(isDebugEnabled);
 await Purchases.setup(kRevenueCatApiKey, appUserId: uid);
```

Is there anything I missed? (but most of the time it works)

Comment: What do you mean with "at startup"? Also, where are you calling getPurchaserInfo? It is being called before your app has the chance to call Purchases.setup

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I finally solve the problem. At start up means I called it immediately after authenticating user. I have fixed the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem. So whenever `getPurchaserInfo` is called, but if `Purchaser.setup` hasn't finish processing, then it will fire this exception. Thanks to the comment by @Cesar above.

In my case, I found the problem was because:

- I had two Blocs that handles IAP and Business logic respectively.
- The IAP calls `Purchases.setup` as soon as the user is authenticated. Then at the main screen, the Business logic will check validity of local data with server by doing `getPurchaserInfo`.
- The problem comes when the internet connection is not great and `getPurchaserInfo` gets fired by Business logic bloc before `Purchases.setup` finish processing.

So the solution I did was by making sure that Business logic bloc starts initializing once IAP bloc done with `Purchases.setup`. Such as placing them in an async function that awaits for each process.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I did not call : *Purchases.configure()*

```dart
await Purchases.configure(PurchasesConfiguration(_apiKey));
```